# add JQuery element to datatable td

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

```
tableObject = $("#example1").DataTable({
    columns: [{ title: "Client Id" }, { title: "City" }]
});

var clientId = value['client_id'];
var editCitySmall = $("<small>", {
                        id: "editCity_" + clientId,
                        "onclick": "editCity('" + clientId + "')",
                        "class": "label pull-right bg-blue editTd"
                    });

tableObject.row.add([clientId, editCitySmall]).draw(false);
```

It's not wrk, in the column "city" print this => [object Object]

How can i insert `<small>` in column ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were nearly there except you're returning an object rather than a string that DataTables expects. Try something like this instead:

```
var editCitySmall = $("<small/>", {
    "id": "editCity_" + clientId,
    "onclick": "editCity('" + clientId + "')",
    "class": "label pull-right bg-blue editTd"
}).prop("outerHTML");
```

That way you're returning the text of the `small` object you've just created.

Let me know how you get on and if possible try to add a JSFiddle...